# Flot line chart; bug with time mode

Tags: javascript, flot

I have a problem when I use Flot

[image: flot line error]

I notice that it happens at the same minute but different second

**2018/10/16 13:12:55   71.755**

**2018/10/16 13:12:09   71.700**

2018/10/16 13:10:52 70.781

Here is my configuration:

```
//Display graph
    $.plot($("#data-chart"), ds, {
        colors: [$chrt_second, $chrt_fourth, "#666", "#BBB"],
        grid: {
            show: true,
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            tickColor: $chrt_border_color,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: $chrt_border_color

        },
        zoom: {
            interactive: true
        },
        pan: {
            interactive: true
        },
        selection: {
            mode: "xy"
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: 5,
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",



        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            ticks: 5,
            max: 110,
            panRange: [-10000, 10000]
        },

        tooltip: true,
        legend: {
            show: true,
            noColumns: 4, // number of colums in legend table
            labelFormatter: null, // fn: string -> string
            labelBoxBorderColor: "#000", // border color for the little label boxes
            container: null, // container (as jQuery object) to put legend in, null means default on top of graph
            position: "ne", // position of default legend container within plot
            margin: [5, 10], // distance from grid edge to default legend container within plot
            backgroundColor: "#efefef", // null means auto-detect
            backgroundOpacity: 1 // set to 0 to avoid background
        },
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "<b>Date: %x</b> = <span>%y.3</span>",
            dateFormat: "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S",
            defaultTheme: false
        },
    });
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want Y axis as minutes ?

Comment: not looked at image the dots do not connect correctly when the minute contains 2 dots at different seconds

Comment: Ok bug corrected by sorting

Comment: Yes, that is a not correctly sorted dataset. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24058467/2610249